# Removing a network printer via login script

Tags: batch-file, printing, cmd, server, network-printers

So, I have implemented some new print software on our print server to monitor print costs per user and per department at our office. Now, I need to remove all of the printers except for the plotters, and install one new printer. The reason being, this "one new printer" is actually the print software on the server.

The script I have so far is

```
:: Uninstall Old Printers
printui.exe /dn /n \\ServerNameHere\printer one
printui.exe /dn /n \\ServerNameHere\printer two
printui.exe /dn /n \\ServerNameHere\printer three
printui.exe /dn /n \\ServerNameHere\printer four
printui.exe /dn /n \\ServerNameHere\printer five

:: Install New Printer
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /in /n \\ServerNameHere\FindMe
```

I keep getting access denied errors and unable to connect to printer errors. But I also, do not want the printers to actually be deleted from the server, just from the local computer.

Any ideas?

And yes, I have tried running the script inside an administrator cmd, as well as launching the script as administrator. Can this solution be fixed? Is there a better solution? I need to perform this task for a little over 100 users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the printer admin scripts in C:\WINDOWS\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US

Comment: That I have not. Had never really thought of going the vbs route. Will definitely look into that. Thanks.